# Load Argument must contain a string, strcat MATLAB

Tags: matlab, load

Hi I'm using this code in MATLAB

```
var1=get(handles.listbox1,'String');
var2=get(handles.listbox1,'Value');
var3=var1(var2);
set(handles.text16,'String',var3)
var4 = strcat('C:\Users\Mehdi BEJAOUI\Desktop\TestL\MATLAB_temp\HBM\HBM\',var3,'')
load(var4) ;
```

When I run the programme I get this error : 
Error using load
Argument must contain a string.

but when I use `load('C:\Users\Mehdi BEJAOUI\Desktop\TestL\MATLAB_temp\HBM\HBM\NameOfAnyFile')` , itw works perfectly

Comment: You may need a file extension at the end of your string if it's not already included? e.g. `.mat`. Can you give an example of what `var1` and `var2` might be? Also on the second to last line, why are you concatenating an empty string after `var3`?

Comment: thank you for responding

the empry string it's because I've tried using an extension, but it does not work 

var1 = 

    '.'
    '..'
    'Deplacement__CH125'
    'Displacement_C__CH237'
    'Displacement_T__CH238'
    'Force__CH124'
    'J_100__CH86'
    'J_101__CH88'
    'J_102__CH89'
    'J_103_Cal_C__CH206'
    'J_103_Cal_T__CH232'

var2 =

     9


var3 = 

    'J_102__CH89'

and then i have var4='C:\Users\Mehdi BEJAOUI\Desktop\TestL\MATLAB_temp\HBM\HBM\J_102__CH89'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run it what is `var4` set to? I suspect, looking at this, that `var1` returns a cell array. `var3` is then set to a 1x1 cell array. With the `strcat` function you are then concatenating a cell array and a string, and Matlab might consider the cell array to be the lowest common denominator, setting `var4` to a cell array, which `load()` does not like. This would not happen if you just typed out the full string.

In short, I believe using curly brackets here `var3 = var{var2}` might solve your problem.

Comment: after 'strcat', error in loading? --------------- data = load(fname);